# Objective C: don´t lock iPhone while app is running

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I was trying to find out how to disable locking iphone while my app is running but I wasn´t succesful. Do you know if it is even possible? My app is reading values from some hardware in real time and it is really annoying when display is locking all the time. I am not talking about running app in the background... Thank you guys!

Comment: If this were possible it would be a violation of security policies.

Comment: Do you mean auto lock? Try `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`

Comment: @Desdenova that's exactly right.

Comment: @mah No, it isn't. It's a public API.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disable the [idleTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled) on UIApplication:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't disable the locking, the user will be always able to lock the phone. However, you can disable the timer (auto lock) using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```